# How to display random strings from json file in SwiftUI?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I created a json file with a bunch of different gift strings in them how do I display it randomly in my view mainly to fit a rectangle in SwiftUI.

//model

```
struct Quote: Codable {
    var text: String
    var author: String

    var shareMessage: String {
        return "\"\(text)\" — \(author)"
    }
}
```

//json file

```
[
    {
        "text": "There are some days when I think I am going to die from an overdose of satisfaction.",
        "author": "Salvador Dali"
    },
    {
        "text": "End each day with thoughts of peace. Begin each day with thoughts of peace.",
        "author": "Anonymous"
    },
    {
        "text": "Don't agonize. Organize.",
        "author": "Anonymous"
    },
    {
        "text": "To look back all the time is boring. Excitement lies in tomorrow.",
        "author": "Natalia Makrova"
    }
]
```

// in the content view
// ik i have to use a randomelement to randomly select a quote but idk how to pass it into the content view.

//I've done error checking for the json data so that's fine

let quotes = Bundle.main.decode([Quote].self, from: "quotes.json")
var chosenQuote = quotes.randomElement()

// the view of I want to display it in is like a rounded rectangle.

```
VStack {
   VStack {
     Text("quote text")
        .font(title3)
        .forgroundColor(.white)
     Text("author"
        .font(title3)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}.frame(width: 240, height: 70).backgroundColor(Color.blue).cornerRadius(7.0)
```

Comment: Swift Array provides [randomElement()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994747-randomelement)

Comment: but how do I place it into the view @vadian

Comment: that what Idk how to do could you assist me please.

Comment: ok I'll update my question.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile but basically replace the literal strings with `chosenQuote!.text` and `chosenQuote!.author`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are most of the way there. Lots of little compilation errors in your `View` code. I'm assuming you're using `decode` from here: `https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-decode-json-from-your-app-bundle-the-easy-way`

`onAppear` seems like a reasonable place to load the quote, although you could certainly choose to do this in a variety of different ways.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var quote : Quote?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let quote = quote {
                VStack {
                   VStack {
                    Text(quote.text)
                        .font(.system(.title3))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text(quote.author)
                        .font(.system(.title3))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }.frame(width: 240)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7.0).fill(Color.blue))
            }
        }.onAppear {
            let quotes = Bundle.main.decode([Quote].self, from: "quotes.json")
            quote = quotes.randomElement()
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted a new quote every time the `View` is re-rendered, you could do something like this instead:

```
struct ContentView2 : View {
    let quotes = Bundle.main.decode([Quote].self, from: "quotes.json")
    
    var quote : Quote { quotes.randomElement()! }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           VStack {
            Text(quote.text)
                .font(.system(.title3))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Text(quote.author)
                .font(.system(.title3))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }.frame(width: 240)
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7.0).fill(Color.blue))
    }
}
```

I'm using force unwrapping with `!` in that example, which isn't generally a great idea, but this is assuming you have total control over the JSON file and are 100% confident that it'll load the quotes correctly.

I'd also note that if the JSON file were huge, you probably want to limit the number of times it was loaded for performance reasons. My first solution is better in that regard.

Comment: As you are mentioning *performance reasons*: `RoundedRectangle...fill` is discouraged. `.background(Color.blue).cornerRadius(7.0)` is less expensive.

Comment: @vadian interesting. Didn't know that. Is there a link with some of this documented?

Comment: @jnpdx, yes  I was using resources from hackingswift

Comment: Please watch mistake #1 in https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/224/common-swiftui-mistakes-and-how-to-fix-them

Comment: I see that addresses the verbosity of the code, but does not seem to reference performance. Either way, I'll try to get in the habit of the less verbose version (although something about the explicitness of `RoundedRect` to say *exactly* what it is is appealing to me).